# Quitar \n \r de un json C#

Tags: c#, json

Hola amigos tengo un endpoint que necesito consumir y me devuelve un json lleno de `\n y \r`, es este:

> "{\r\n  \"Table\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7085.0,\r\n
>   \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO AGROSUMATE CONSUMO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n
>   \"CLAVE_P\": 7086.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO AUTOMOTRIZ\"\r\n
>   },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7087.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\":
>   \"CREDITO DE NOMINA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\":
>   7088.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO ESCOLAR\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7089.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO
>   PYME\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7057.0,\r\n
>   \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO AL PEQUE?O EMPRESARIO SALDOS INSOLUTOS -\"\r\n
>   },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7061.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\":
>   \"CLIENTE DISTINGUIDO SALDOS INSOLUTOS -\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n
>   \"CLAVE_P\": 7063.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"AMPLIACION DE CREDITO
>   SALDOS INSOLUTOS - \"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\":
>   7055.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO SOLIDARIO SALDOS INSOLUTOS -\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7065.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO INDIVIDUAL REESTRUCTURA - RENOVACION SALDOS
>   INSOLUTO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7066.0,\r\n
>   \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO AL PEQUE?O EMP. REESTRUCTURA - RENOVACION
>   SALDOS IN-\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7058.0,\r\n
>   \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO RURAL SALDOS INSOLUTOS -\"\r\n    },\r\n
>   {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7059.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO
>   COMUNAL SALDOS INSOLUTOS -\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\":
>   7064.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO SOLIDARIO REESTRUCTURA - RENOVACION SALDOS INSOLUTO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\":
>   7067.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO RURAL REESTRUCTURA - RENOVACION SALDOS INSOLUTOS -\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n
>   \"CLAVE_P\": 7068.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO COMUNAL
>   REESTRUCTURA - RENOVACION SALDOS INSOLUTOS-\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n
>   \"CLAVE_P\": 7069.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO DE AMPLIACION
>   COMUNAL SALDOS INSOLUTOS -\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\":
>   7056.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO INDIVIDUAL SALDOS INSOLUTOS - \"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7091.0,\r\n
>   \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO VOCEADORES\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n
>   \"CLAVE_P\": 7090.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"SUMALE A TU CASA\"\r\n
>   },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7092.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\":
>   \"BOSI SUMATE\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7093.0,\r\n
>   \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO PYME RESTRUCTURA RENOVACION\"\r\n    },\r\n
>   {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\": 7094.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO
>   MEDIANO EMPRESARIO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_P\":
>   7095.0,\r\n      \"PRODUCTO\": \"CREDITO AGROSUMATE\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}"

Necesito quitar esos saltos para poder  serializar y deserializar mi json; esto es lo que he estado intenando sin éxito:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://miapi/micontrolador/GetProductos");

        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {

            case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):

                string xjson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var json2 = string.Join(" ", Regex.Split(xjson, @"(?:\\r\\n|\\n|\\r)"));
                json2 = json2.Replace("\\", "");
                json2 = json2.Replace("\"", "");

                dynamic stuff  = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json2);
                break;
            default:
                // Msn.Text = "Hudo algun error";
                break;

        }
```

la cuestion es que al examinar json2, sigo obteniendo lo mismo. ¿Alguien sabe que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente el problema es que en el json estas viendo literal el simbolo \n no es un salto de linea. siendo ésto cierto, debería funcionarte lo siguiente:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://miapi/micontrolador/GetProductos");


switch (response.StatusCode)
{

    case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):




        string xjson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var json2 = string.Join(" ", Regex.Split(xjson, @"(?:\\r\\n|\\n|\\r)"));

        break;
    default:
        // Msn.Text = "Hudo algun error";
        break;

}
```

Espero te sea util, saludos.

Comment: Lo que he cambiado es \n por \\n para que el \ que se va a reemplazar sea de manera literal que es como se devuelve en json y no un simbolo escapado cómo \n (salto de linea)

Comment: ya, oye si me ayudo mucho, pero quiero usar ese mismo json para llenar un picker , crees que podrías ayudarme, actualizaré mi pregunta hasta lo que tengo ahora.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
  var json2 = xjson.Replace("\r\n", "");
```

incluso te recomiendo también reemplazar los caracteres `\"`

```
 var json2 = xjson.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace(@"\", "");
```

Realiza el cambio:

```
 ...
 ...
 case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):

                string xjson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //var json2 = string.Join(" ", Regex.Split(xjson, @"(?:\\r\\n|\\n|\\r)"));
                var json2 = xjson.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace(@"\", "");

                dynamic stuff  = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json2);
                break;
...
...
```